# Timer doesn't feel like overriding

Tags: java, timer, overriding, superclass

A friend of mine gave me this code for a timer. I must say that I'm a beginner, so I don't understand what @Override is, but the code worked for other friends.

- tijd is an int with the value of 10
- lx is the x value of a label
- s1 is also an int with a value of 3

Eclipse says about the public void line:

> Multiple markers at this line:
>
> - The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) of type new ActionListener(){} must override a superclass method
> - implements java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed

The code is:

```
 final Timer t = new Timer(tijd, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lx = lx-s1;
    }
});
t.start();
```

With it comes the suggestion of deleting `@Override`, but as I'm not sure of what it does I don't know if I'll be deleting an important thing of the code. I suppose it isn't there because some-one thought it would be funny to include the code.

So my questions are:
1. How do I move the label?
2. What is the problem with `@Override`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RealSkeptic How to move the label, and what the problem is with Override

Comment: `@Override` tells the compiler that you expect to be overriding a method from the parent class or interface (this case from `ActionListener`), it provides a means by which the compiler can tell you when you've made a mistake.  Make sure you are importing `java.awt.event.ActionListener`, `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` and `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I had already imported those 3. Does that mean I can remove @Override?

Comment: About moving the label: this is not entirely trivial, because in Swing, the position of a label is usually determined by its container. You should post all relevant code and maybe a screen shot. Generally speaking, you'll need to access one of the GUI components - just changing a variable won't affect the GUI objects. As for `@Override` - is Eclipse actually giving you an error there or just a warning?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Eclipse gives an error for the public void line, suggesting to remove Override. When I do this the error is solved but the program still doesn't work

Comment: Well, removing `@Override` is safe, I believe. But you still have to actually change a component to move your label. Just adding a value to a variable is not going to do anything. Without more code, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: You could remove it, but it's not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, indeed the @Override is negligible in this case. Yet, the codes for moving the label is of great importance. 
You should base it on this:

In the action listener of the timer do something like this: x = x - 1;
And then Label.setLocation(x,y);

That should do the trick!

Comment: It did! Thank you, you are my hero :D

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is creating on the spot an anonymous implementation of the ActionListener interface and passing this directly as the second argument of the Timer constructor Timer(int x, ActionListener y).
Any implementation of this interface must provide an implementation of the method ActionPerformed (ActionEvent e), so you provide this in place. Implementations of an interface method have to be annotated with the @Override tag as of Java 6. If you're using Java 5 it's optional.
You could have written your code like this, using a named (non-anonymous) class:

```
static class LabelMover implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  ...
  }
}

Timer timer = new Timer (tijd, new LabelMover());
```

This would lead to the same behavior.
The question is however: which Timer class are you using here? The Java Timer class (java.util.Timer) does not have a constructor that takes an ActionListener as a second parameter.
If you want to have the label moved incrementally every so many milliseconds then you should create a TimerTask that does that and then create a Timer and schedule the TimerTask with that timer:

```
static class LabelMover implements TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // code to move the label
    }
}
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(), 0, tijd);
```

Comment: OP seems to be using [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), not `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: That's true. Thank you anyways, maybe I can use this one if mine continues to give errors

Comment: @Canelaguila You better stick to javax.swing.Timer, as it ensures the modifications are done in the event dispatching thread, which is important in Swing applications.

Comment: Which would then mean the op would be violating the single thread rules of Swing, so, no, they shouldn't be using your example

Comment: Hey, don't shoot! I explicitly asked what Timer class was used. Lacking that information I had to guess and picked a Timer I know. I took my time to explain the @Override matter, which was what the question was about. So give me some credit.